# Android ENOENT error while trying to write a file

Tags: java, android, file-handling

I've seen pretty many questions stating the same problem but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code.
I'm new to using Uri's and don't really understand what's happening.
Firstly, the code which is responsible to start the activity for camera to take the pictures:

```
void cameraAction() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

Now the code where the problem arises:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        bitmapOptions);

                viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                String path = Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                OutputStream outFile;
                String fileName = "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                File file = new File(path, fileName);
                try {//This is where the ENOENT error is shown
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the *Phoenix/default/* folder already exist on your external storage?

Comment: @adelphus I think no, I assumed the method will create the directory by itself. Thanks for the quick reply! Can you guide me to a way to fix this?

Comment: No - you must create any directories first. `File.mkdirs()` should help.

Comment: @adelphus Are you talking about 'java.io.File.mkdirs()'?

Comment: @adelphus So I may use `File file = new File(path, fileName);` and then `file.mkdirs();` and it'd work without any problem? Doesn't seem like it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the path exists by calling [mkdirs()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) before trying to create the file:

```
String path = Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator
        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";

if (new File(path).mkdirs()) {
    OutputStream outFile;
    String fileName = "" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(path, fileName);        
    ...
}
```

Don't forget the permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!, shouldn't have wasted my entire day to fix this.